# Area of set in complex plane

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, complex-analysis

Let $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ be two bounded open set in the complex plane and $f:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ an analytic function. We then define
$$ A = \bigcup_{y \in \Omega_1}\{ (z,x) \in \mathbb C\times \Omega_2;  z^2 = y f(x) \}.$$

Can we give a formula for the volume of the set $A$ in terms of $f$ and the volume of $\Omega_1$?

Comment: one road is to expand the expression under the root and simplify it using trig; tedious but will likely make things much easier

Comment: In the last equation, how are $dx$ and $dy$ related to $y_1$ and $y_2$?

Comment: Your title should be descriptive. A $\rm\LaTeX$ only title is typically frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that points $x \in \Omega_2$ with $f(x) = 0$ do not contribute to the volume since they correspond to points of the form $(0, x)\in A$. Therefore, in the following we consider only $x \in \Omega_2$ with $f(x) \neq 0$. For a fixed $(z,x)$ the equation $z^2 = yf(x)$ has a unique solution for $y$. For fixed $y\in\Omega_1$, $x\in\Omega_2$ there are two solutions: $z = \pm \sqrt{yf(x)}$. Therefore, we have

$$ \text{Vol}(A) = 2\int_{\Omega_2\times\Omega_1} dxd\bar{x}d(yf(x))^{1/2} d\left(\overline{yf(x)}\right)^{1/2} = \frac12 \int_{\Omega_2\times\Omega_1} \frac{\left|f(x)\right|}{\left|y\right|} dxd\bar{x}dyd\bar{y}.$$

Note that $dxd\bar{x} = dx_1dx_2$, where we represent $x$ as $x=x_1+ix_2$ for $x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{R}$. The same for $dyd\bar{y}$. Therefore, if one prefers, we can rewrite
$$ \text{Vol}(A) = \frac12 \int_{\Omega_2\times\Omega_1} \frac{\left|f(x)\right|}{\left|y\right|} dx_1dx_2dy_1dy_2.$$